# Add JInternalFrame to JDesktopPane using a button inside other JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane, swingutilities

This snippet code I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6868039/2240900

> how to add the internal2 to desktoppane1 using a button placed somewhere in internal1.

In the ActionListener added to your button you can use code like the following to get a reference to the desktop pane:

```
Container container = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JDesktopPane.class, (Component)event.getSource());

if (container != null)
{
    JDesktopPane desktop = (JDesktopPane)container;
    JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame(...);
    desktop.add( frame );
}
```

My question is how to add another JInternalFrame if the button reside in another JInternalFrame? ex: add internalX to desktoppane1 using a button placed somewhere in internal2/internal3/internalX, where each internal was created using a button inside internalX not using a menubar.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally find out that we can use a method of JInternalFrame that is getDesktopPane().
As mention in javadoc:

```
getDesktopPane

    public JDesktopPane getDesktopPane()

Convenience method that searches the ancestor hierarchy for a JDesktop instance. If JInternalFrame finds none, the desktopIcon tree is searched.

Returns:
    the JDesktopPane this internal frame belongs to, or null if none is found
```

So we can just use a command like:

```
JDesktopPane desktopPane = internalFrame.getDesktopPane();
desktopPane.add(internalX);
```

or if the class extends JInternalFrame simply use

```
JDesktopPane desktopPane = this.getDesktopPane();
desktoppane.add(internalX);
```

to get the JDesktopPane to add another JInternalFrame in a nested JInternalFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Externalize the listener into it's own class, with proper parameters if needed.  Then, you can instantiate this listener every time you create a new frame and apply it to its button.

Comment: Why I need to externalize the listener and which listerner do you mean? I only need to add the internalX to desktoppane1 show it shows as a window inside my application, not as a window outside my application.

Comment: Then I'm not understanding your problem.  Show us code (a full SSCCE) that works for one frame, and show us why it doesn't work for more frames.